# Flash Builder on Mac OS "Source not found Problem"

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sdk, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4 on my MAC. Flex SDK 4.0. Flash Player 10.1

By executing this code below I only see the trace saying "start". And if I look at the Declaration of the ENTER_FRAME is see the error saying: "Source could not be found for flash.events.Event.Enter_Frame in...."

But the playerglobal.swc source is there, and I have tried different SDK versions and FP versions.

If this is a Flash Builder problem I can not be the only one having this issue ?

TY for any help.

package
{

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Test extends Sprite
{
    public function Test()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
        trace("start");
    }

    private function enterFrame(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace("I am in enterframe");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Source code for `flash.*` package isn't available as far as it is an internal implementation of Flash Player. `playerglobal.swc` contains only declarations of classes, methods and properties but no source code. So you haven't any chance to see the sources in the Flash Builder with any version of Flex SDK or Flash Player.

Comment: Ty Constantiner, I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand how can I get it to execute the ENTER_FRAME / output the trace("I am in enterframe") ?

Comment: You need to run your application in debugger and see all the traces in debug console.